# Calling JS function from html/php file without button

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

I'm trying to call my JS function which is in a file called Scripts.js. I have a php function, but I'm unsure as to whether I need to come out the php function or not as I can't get it to work either way and nothing I've googled is giving a definitive answer as to which it should be so any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['renameFile']))    
{
    //uses checkboxes from table
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
        $checkedboxes = $_POST['checkbox'];
        $count = count($checkedboxes);
        //echo ("$count");

        /*if($count == 0)
        {
            throw error that something needs to be selected. If implement checkbox hidden then no need to implement 
        }*/

         if($count == 1)
        {?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                showUpload();
            </script>
            <?php
        }
?>
```

So I'm calling the function showUpload() in my Scripts.js file which I have defined in my main screen using

```
<script src ="Scripts.js"> </script>
```

Which I know works as I've used it elsewhere.

```
function showUpload()
{
    document.getElementById('fileUpload').style.display = "block";
}
```

And then this goes on to call a pop up form which I can get to work on a button click so it's just calling it without a button which seems to be an issue. Thanks!

Comment: maybe php run before the page is loaded. You can maybe check the count and print on document ready?

Comment: try running it after you are sure the page is loaded completely `window.onload = function () { showUpload(); }`

Comment: I originally had count printing to check it had loaded and it still did the same thing. And still no luck ensure it's loaded completely. :(

Answer (score 0):

check following things.

1. include your js file at the top of the file
2. write the script tag out side the php mode.
3. make sure the if conditions are true/false as you expect

then the code should work fine